# scss class selector in span

Tags: class, sass, css-selectors

I feel very stupid for asking this question because I think I miss out something.
I have the following HTML code:

```
<span class="label-link-text">[help]</span>
```

Now, I want to style the span using the class selector like this:

```
span {
  .label-link-text {
    font-size: 15pt;
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Sadly, it doesn't work like that.
But instead, this is working fine:

```
span {
  &[class="label-link-text"] {
    font-size: 15pt;
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Can somebody explain it to me? I thought the class selector should work like in the first example?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MrjGqe

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing this:

```
span {
    .class {}
}
```

Targets elements with the class `class` that are children of a span:

```
<span><div class="class"></div></span>
```

What you want is this:

```
span {
    &.class {}
}
```

By using the `&` parent selector, you target `span`s with the class `class`:

```
<span class="class"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
span {
  &.label-link-text {
    font-size: 15pt;
    color: red;
  }
}
```